# C++ extern variable exception (Solved)

Tags: c++, variables, declaration, definition, extern

```
extern int eg_i = 0;

int main(){
++eg_i;    // 1
return 0;
}
```

This code surprisingly throws no compile error.

Because if an extern variable is declared with initialization, it is taken as the definition of the variable as well.

I didn't know there's an exception for the extern keyword.

Comment: I can't see any undefined variables in the sample code

Comment: *"the 'eg_i' increases everytime 'test' being called."* -- that is bizarre, considering that `eg_i` is not used anywhere (which could explain the lack of a link error). Did you copy-paste your code, or did you try to re-type it and introduce typos in the process? Definitely prefer the former.

Comment: C++ should be learnt using a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by trial and error. In particular, `extern int eg_i = 0;` is a definition which is explained in any beginner level c++ book.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
extern int eg_i = 0;
```

is a definition of the variable `eg_i` because there is present an initializer.

So there is no problem.

From the C++ 17 Standard (6.1 Declarations and definitions)

> 2 A declaration is a definition unless
>
> (2.2) — it contains the extern specifier (10.1.1) or a
> linkage-specification26 (10.5) and neither an initializer nor a
> function-body,

By the way it seems there are typos within the function `test`. It should look like

```
void test(){
++sgi;
++egi
++eg_i;
}
```

Comment: *"there is a typo"* -- Just one typo? You're OK with the third plus sign and lack of a semicolon on the second line? ;)

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks. I have updated this statement.